# openssl_free_key expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, php-openssl

I have this code:

```
openssl_pkcs12_read($p12buf, $p12cert, $decPass);
openssl_pkey_export($p12cert['pkey'], $pemkey); 
openssl_sign($toSign, $signature, $pemkey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
openssl_free_key($pemkey);
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning (2): openssl_free_key() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

How can i get rid of it or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[openssl_free_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-free-key.php) require the result (resource) of [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) or [openssl_pkey_get_public](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php)

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($keyFile, $passphrase);
openssl_free_key($key);
```

Comment: openssl_free_key(openssl_pkey_get_private($pemkey)); 
seems to work just fine. Thank you!